# Limits used as exponents -- how to write under the limit symbol without using \displaymath?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

If one needs to write a limit as an exponent, one might have this dilemma: if you use `\displaymath`, "x to infinity" will be nicely printed under the lim symbol, but your exponent will be using the normal font and will appear very big on the page. If you take out the `\displaymath` instruction, the exponent will use the small font, but now the part "x to infinity" is not a subscript to the "lim" symbol anymore, it just follows it. Trying to use any font size instructions with `\displaystyle`, or actually inside the math mode, does not seem to work for me! Does anybody know any trick to get around this?

This is the horrible expression I am fighting with (might be easier to make my point this way):

```
$e^{\left(\, \displaystyle \lim_{x \,\rightarrow\, \infty} 
\frac{\, 2x \sin{\frac{1}{x}} \,}{ 1 \,-\, \sin{\frac{1}{x}}} 
\,\right) } \,;$
```

I can't get the last exponent to behave, because it contains the limit (it's the last exponent, the one for the number `e`). If I take out the `\displaystyle`, the limit gets messed up, as explained above.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest you to use the `exp(...)` notation instead of `e^{}`; you can force the below position for the limit using `\limits`; since you are writing this expresion as in-line math I would also suggest using `1/x` instead of `\frac{1}{x}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\exp\left(\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\, 2x \sin(1/x) \,}{ 1 - \sin(1/x)}\right)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Such a big expression should probably go as a displayed equation:

```
\[
e^{\left(\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} 
  \frac{2x \sin\frac{1}{x}}{1-\sin\frac{1}{x}}\right)};
\]
```

but the result will be bad anyway, because the exponent will be much bigger than the basis.

I suggest you

```
\[
\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}
  \frac{2x \sin\frac{1}{x}}{1-\sin\frac{1}{x}}\right);
\]
```

which has not the problem.

[image]

You are using many manual spaces which shouldn't be used.

Comment: I know manual spaces are hard to read, but there is no way to get a polished aspect without using them, or at least I don't know of a better one. If I take the manual spaces out, all of a sudden that expression looks a lot uglier and less readable to day the least! I am not defending the manual spaces, all I am saying is that I do not know of another way to produce an elegant output.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers give advice on how to re-write your expression. The advice works well in this instance as you can use `exp`, but there may be cases in the future when this is not an option- such as if the problem used `3` instead of `e`

If you would like to keep with the idea of keeping the limit in the exponent, then you can use `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package to make it a bit more manageable.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

$e^{\scalebox{1}{$\left( \displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{ 2x \sin{\dfrac{1}{x}} }{ 1 - \sin{\dfrac{1}{x}}} \right)$ }}$

\vspace{0.5cm}

$e^{\scalebox{0.9}{$\left( \displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{ 2x \sin{\dfrac{1}{x}} }{ 1 - \sin{\dfrac{1}{x}}} \right)$ }}$

\vspace{0.5cm}

$e^{\scalebox{0.8}{$\left( \displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{ 2x \sin{\dfrac{1}{x}} }{ 1 - \sin{\dfrac{1}{x}}} \right)$ }}$

\vspace{0.5cm}

$e^{\scalebox{0.7}{$\left( \displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{ 2x \sin{\dfrac{1}{x}} }{ 1 - \sin{\dfrac{1}{x}}} \right)$ }}$

\vspace{0.5cm}

$e^{\scalebox{0.6}{$\left( \displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{ 2x \sin{\dfrac{1}{x}} }{ 1 - \sin{\dfrac{1}{x}}} \right)$ }}$

\vspace{0.5cm}

$e^{\scalebox{0.5}{$\left( \displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{ 2x \sin{\dfrac{1}{x}} }{ 1 - \sin{\dfrac{1}{x}}} \right)$ }}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand why replacing `\frac{1}{x}` with `(1/x)`, at the very least, might ever *not* be an option. Separately, doesn't shrinking the size of a complicated formula by 30 percent or more constitute a perfect recipe for rendering it virtually illegible?

Comment: @Mico I agree. In practise I would use the method demonstrated in one of the other answers. However, I thought the OP might like to know of this option with the instructions that it should be used carefully

Comment: Thanks. I certainly agree with your view that it's good to know, at least in principle, how to reduce a formula using the `\scalebox` command.

Comment: Thank you, this \scalebox thing rocks!! I wish I knew of it earlier... now I have to read about it more! Thanks again, Colin.

Comment: 1/x, at least when I use it, takes away a lot from the poetry of math notation, and induces the impression that the software producing that document is somewhat impotent. Personally I don't like to use it because its impact on the aesthetics is devastating, makes an expression like sin 2x/y ambiguous, and somewhat imparts a primitive aspect to the expressions using it. But if space is at a premium maybe then 1/x is the ticket.