# How to deal with the size of the exponential type function's argument?

Tags: math-mode

I have the following function in a report of global size 12 :

```
$Q= \rho V c_{p} \left( T -T_{\infty} \right) [ 1-e^{\frac {h A_s}{\rho V c_{p}}t}]$
```

As one would expect, the exponential function's argument appears very tiny:

[image]

**Now , my question is that**:

Are there ways to make deal with this problem?Some people *may suggest and have suggested) that I change the argument's font size*..that surely is a way but in small font sizes such as font size 12, it looks terrible , and *others suggest to use the `exp` function* , but I feel that , that answer applies to a class of functions that have popular inline alternatives.

Also answers suggested should be within the range of good scientific/mathematical documentation practices.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: I wouldn't use superscripts in this case, I would use the `\exp` notation:  `$Q= \rho V c_{p} ( T -T_{\infty} )\Bigl[ 1-\exp\Bigl({\frac {h A_s}{\rho V c_{p}}t\Bigr)}\Bigr]$`. Perhaps it would also be a good idea to use a displayed expresion.

Comment: [Limits used as exponents -- how to write under the limit symbol without using \displaymath?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36831)

Comment: noted the the point raised in your answer , but how is that any different from what the answer mentioned below..i.e in your answer you scaled the superscript , in the answer mentioned below he scaled the font of the superscript ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
$Q= \rho V c_{p} \left( T -T_{\infty} \right) [ 1-e^{h A_s t / \rho V c_{p}}]$
```

or, if you really want the `t` kept separate from the fraction, then:

```
$Q= \rho V c_{p} \left( T -T_{\infty} \right) [ 1-e^{(h A_s / \rho V c_{p})t}]$
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

A number of possibilities to choose from:

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent Inline math:\\

$Q= \rho V c_{p} ( T -T_{\infty} )
    [ 1-e^{\frac {h A_s}{\rho V c_{p}}t}]$
\quad (pretty bad)\\

$Q= \rho V c_{p} ( T -T_{\infty} )
    \Bigl[ 1 - e^{\scalebox{1.2}{$\frac {h A_s}{\rho V c_{p}}t$}} \Bigr]$
\quad (awful)\\

$Q= \rho V c_{p} ( T -T_{\infty} )
    \Bigl[ 1 - \exp\Bigl({\frac {h A_s}{\rho V c_{p}}t\Bigr)}\Bigr]$
\quad (better)\\[1em]

\noindent Display math:
\[
    Q= \rho V c_{p} \left( T -T_{\infty} \right)
        \left[ 1-\exp{\left( \frac {h A_s}{\rho V c_{p}} t \right)} \right]
        \quad \text{(much better)}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was wondering if your answer would the same if rather than using the exponential function , you were using lets say some other function that did not have a recognized inline type alternative(all the other above restrictions are in place)?

Comment: @nerorevenge Suppose for the sake of argument `e` was `\theta` then I guess the only possibility is using a few `\frac`tions next to each other in the exponent such that, at least, the readability is preserved as much as possible.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
$Q= \alpha \Delta T \left( 1-e^{\beta t}\right)$,

where $\alpha=\rho V c_{p}$,
$\Delta T=T-T_{\infty}$,
$\beta=h A_s / \alpha$.
```