# Text font in the equation

Tags: math-mode

I'm just wondering if there is a way to make the "t" in my equation (also shown with the red arrow) the same size as the one generated by the \dfrac?

Here is my code:

```
$v = \left[\dfrac{Et}{RC} + 1 \right] \times e^{\left(t-\dfrac{t}{RC}\right)}$
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: why are you using inline math (`$`) for the whole expression, it would be better as a display `\[...\]` ?  but you could use `e^{\textstyle t-...` but better to  avoid the superscript and use `\exp(t-...`

Comment: See also this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115238/123129) to [How to deal with the size of the exponential type function's argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115229/123129). The variant with `\exp` might look better, if all text should have the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you replace

```
e^{\left(t-\dfrac{t}{RC}\right)}
```

with

```
\exp( t-t/RC )
```

for inline math mode and

```
\exp\Bigl(t-\frac{t}{RC}\Bigr)
```

for display math mode. For both math styles, I would also replace `\times` with `\cdot` -- or just omit `\times` entirely.

Note the use of two inline-style fraction expressions in the first row of the following screenshot:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$v = [Et/RC + 1] \cdot \exp(t-t/RC)$

\bigskip
$\displaystyle v=\Bigl[\frac{Et}{RC}+1\Bigr] \cdot 
             \exp\Bigl(t-\frac{t}{RC}\Bigr)$

\end{document}
```

A full MWE (minimum working

Answer (score 5):

Let me spell out @david comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-2] and more text which contain the following equation
$v = \left[\dfrac{Et}{RC} + 1 \right] \times e^{\left(\textstyle t-\dfrac{t}{RC}\right)}$
and more text \lipsum[1][3-5]

Slightly better result you will get when you not use \verb+\dfrac+  and for exponent use \verb+\exp+:
$v = \left[\frac{Et}{RC} + 1 \right] \times \exp{\left(t-\frac{t}{RC}\right)}$.
\lipsum[66].

However, better is:
\lipsum[1][1-2] 
\[
v = \left[\dfrac{Et}{RC} + 1 \right] \times e^{\left(\textstyle t-\dfrac{t}{RC}\right)}
\]
\lipsum[1][3-5] Or better:
\[
v = \left[\frac{Et}{RC} + 1 \right] \times \exp{\left(t-\frac{t}{RC}\right)}
\]
\lipsum[1][6-9]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$v = \left[\dfrac{Et}{RC} + 1 \right] \times e^{\left({\textstyle t}-\dfrac{t}{RC}\right)}$
\end{document}
```

[image]